# Which is the better way to "handle" an exception I want to let bubble up but execute clean up code

Tags: c#

I am working on a new project and have a section of code where I don't want to actually handle exceptions but make sure any DB connections are closed.  I am wondering which will be the best way to handle the issue.  I see 2 ways but am not sure which will be clearer:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

try
{
    con.open()
    //DoStuff
}
catch(Exception)
{
    throw;
}
finally
{
    con.close();
    con.dispose();
}
```

OR

```
try
{
    con.open()
    //DoStuff
}
finally
{
    con.close();
    con.dispose();
}
```

Either way I pass the exception up to the calling code to be handled but still clean up the connections.

Comment: `catch(Exception) { throw; }` is basically a no-op.  There is no reason to catch an exception and then do nothing, but rethrow it.

Comment: The second one is cleaner for sure. But the first one might be useful if your not the only one to touch the code since it tell explicitly to the reader that you want the exception to bubble up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to enclose your connection. It would translate into `try-finally` block, like in your second code example.

Since you are not doing anything with your exception *(like logging)* you can leave out the catch block.

You can use `using` like:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
{

}
```

This will ensure your connection is disposed at the end of `using` block, even in case of an exception. You can only use `using` statement with those objects which implements `IDisposable` interface.

If you are going to deal with objects which doesn't implement `IDisposable` then your second code snippet (With try-finally) is good enough, since you want the exception to bubble up.